# Bad Type in phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

When I try to export the database from phpMyAdmin getting the error.

Refer to the below screenshot.
[image]

I don't know how this issue is happening.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Comment: version number : 5.6.12

Comment: This is not a phpMyAdmin version number.

Comment: Sorry @MarcDelisle ver : 4.0.4

Comment: I could not reproduce your problem in 4.0.4 when selecting a database and clicking on Export.

Comment: If you copy the database to a new database (from the Operations tab), can you export the newly created one without error? Anything special about your database structure?

Comment: Does this happen when you export a different database?

Comment: i am using this database only for Magento. all other database's are exporting fine. even i can able to export the single table's on error database, but i could not able to do export the entire database "local_magento" as per screen shot.please advise

Comment: What format are you trying to export to? Do other formats work?

Comment: I am experiencing this same issue for a WordPress DB. ManKingdom have you found a solution?

Comment: I have the same problem when trying to export a table. Still waiting for a solution

Comment: I have this exact same problem. I am having this problem only on my 5.6 mysql database and not the 5.5 ones. I think that 5.6.12 was the database version that Man Kingdom posted, as someone else pointed out that it was not a phpmyadmin version.

Comment: Why not try some other MySQL tools to export? eg SIDU.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem & I solved it by increasing the value of 'max_input_vars' on php.ini
Give it a try.

Comment: I have +1'ed this answer, but then discovered that it was just random floating bug. In the end the issue was with cookies and non-persistent sessions behind load balancers